# Add control in resource dictionary style

Tags: wpf, resources, controls

I'm not sure if it's even possible, but worth to try and ask. So - it is possible to add somehow control to resource dictionary?

For example I have style which I apply to every window in my application:

```
<Style x:Key="WindowStyle" TargetType="Window">
        <Setter Property="WindowState" Value="Maximized" />
        <Setter Property="WindowStyle" Value="None" />
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth}}" />
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight}}" />
        <Setter Property="Background">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="/myApp;component/Pictures/gradientBackground.png" />
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Icon" Value="/myApp;component/Pictures/logo_small.png" />
    </Style>
```

As you can see every window is maximized and have no borders etc - it's just full screen window. What I'd like to do is add simple button in the right-top corner, which will work as minimize.

Any idea?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
   <Style x:Key="WindowStyle" TargetType="Window">
        <Setter Property="WindowState" Value="Maximized" />
        <Setter Property="WindowStyle" Value="None" />
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth}}" />
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight}}" />
        <Setter Property="Background">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="/myApp;component/Pictures/gradientBackground.png" />
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Icon" Value="/myApp;component/Pictures/logo_small.png" />
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Button Content="X" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="2"></Button>
                        <ContentControl Grid.Row="1" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"></ContentControl>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>

        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Comment: Not really. Now in every window i have only this button without any otner controls ;)